# Can't add items to recyclerView using arraylist

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm using a firebase database for my app. 
I can add and retrieve data from the database but when I'm trying to add my retrieved data in an arraylist I can't populate the arraylist.

```
 public void retrievePosts(){

    retrievePosts.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "There are " + dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount() + " blog posts", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();

            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Post post = postSnapshot.getValue(Post.class);
                //adding data to the list
                  Toast toastNew = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), post.getAuthor()+"_"+post.getTitle()+"_"+post.getContent(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toastNew.show();
                postList.add(post);

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
            Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(coordinatorLayout, "Unable to fetch posts", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
            snackbar.show();
        }
    });

}
```

This retrievePosts method is parsing my datas, and postList.add(post); line I'm trying to add data to the arraylist.
I've initialized the arraylist before calling the retrievePosts(); method and then tried to add the arraylist in my recyclyerView

```
 postList = new ArrayList<Post>();
    retrievePosts();
    fab= (com.melnykov.fab.FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

    mAdapter = new MyRecyclerViewAdapter(postList);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Can't find what I'm doing wrong. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the error that you are seeing? Is there any stackTrace that you can post?

Comment: There are no errors in the stackTrace, my problem is I can see the data in the toast, but after trying to add them in the arraylist, the recyclerView stays empty.

Comment: So your arraylist does get populated, but your view is not getting updated, Modify your question title to "Recyclerview not showing newly added items"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your adapter has a reference to `postList`, then it also needs to be told when `postList` changes, so that it can tell the RecyclerView that it needs to re-query it (the adapter) for updated views.

You can do this with the [`notifyDataSetChanged()` method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()) on the `RecyclerView.Adapter`.

---

You should be wary - though it's unlikely, it is possible that the posts will be retrieved before your adapter is initialised (leading to a null pointer exception if you use my answer above). I would move the `retrievePosts()` call to be last.

Comment: @mufad if this solves your problem, your question will need re-tagging and probably a re-titling will help other users.